# Discord.py send dynamic time string

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on a Bot where users can ask to play a game and set when to play it:
`.play Valorant #30`  `->` `"@anyone_who_is_playing_valorant, up for a round in 30 minutes?"`

Currently, I'm editing the message every minute to display the correct time left, which unfortunately makes implementing other commands and functions way more difficult as it should be (while loop etc).

My only solution would be to display the time at which 30 minutes would be passed:
**Message written at 17:00** `->` `"@anyone_who_is_playing_valorant, up for a round at 17:30?"`
but due to timezones the displayed timestring has to be different for each user.

Actually, Discord supports such a function for [embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.timestamp), but I haven't found a standart support for sending dynamic timestrings. I would imagine it to be like Pings, where there is no function but a syntax for it: `<@!authorid>`

Is there a way to send dynamic timestrings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a way to have a dynamic string in your message but it does not work for the footer in the embed.
You only need to make a unix code,

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

date = datetime.utcnow()
utc_time = calendar.timegm(date.utctimetuple())
print(utc_time)
```

your output looks something like this: **1657723929**

You format the code to this: <t:unixcode:R>
and it gives you
**7 minutes ago**

You can also make a timestamp which leads to the future with just adding the secconds to the unix code you just made e.g.:
this code **<t:2665824929:R>** represents

**in 32 years**

depends on when you see this because its dynamic

Answer (score 2):

There is no dynamic time syntax in Discord messaging, the only such functionality is the `timestamp` in embeds as you mentioned.